# Can you set a timeout on the Sony A6300's LCD screen?

Tags: sony, rear-lcd

Is there a way to have the Sony A6300 turn off its LCD screen after a certain number of minutes? For example to turn off the LCD screen after 3 minutes of inactivity. This is to save some power as I find the LCD is always on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Go to Menu -> Setup -> Pwr Save Start Time. You can choose there between  30 Min, 5 Min, 2 Min, 1 Min or 10 Sec.